# How to generate a mock from debug variable values in intellij?

Tags: java, testing, plugins, groovy, intellij-idea

Sometimes I need to mock rather long, to write out, POJOs in my test cases. I was wondering if there is anyway I could generate the mocks from debug variable data in Intellij (14)?

As an example, we have a class:

```
public class MyClass{
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName1;
    private Double aVariableWithARatherLongName2;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName3;
    private Long aVariableWithARatherLongName4;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName5;
    private Boolean aVariableWithARatherLongName6;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName7;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName8;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName9;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName10;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName11;
    private String aVariableWithARatherLongName12;

    //getters & setters
}
```

And within my debug variable view I would have a list of `MyClass` variables:

```
- myClasses = {ArrayList@0} size = 5
    - 0 = {MyClass@1}
        - aVariableWithARatherLongName1 = {String} "value 1"
        - aVariableWithARatherLongName2 = {Double} 2.0
        - aVariableWithARatherLongName3 = {String} "value 1"
        ...
    - 1 = {MyClass@2}
        - aVariableWithARatherLongName1 = {String} "value 2"
        - aVariableWithARatherLongName2 = {Double} 2.0
        - aVariableWithARatherLongName3 = {String} "value 2"
        ...
    + 2 = {MyClass@3}
    + 3 = {MyClass@4}
    + 4 = {MyClass@5}
```

And then the plugin or Intellij would generate something like below based on the selected language (Groovy in this example):

```
def mockedResults(){
    [
        new MyClass(aVariableWithARatherLongName1: 'value 1', aVariableWithARatherLongName2: 2.0, aVariableWithARatherLongName3: 'value 1', ...),
        new MyClass(aVariableWithARatherLongName1: 'value 2', aVariableWithARatherLongName2: 2.0, aVariableWithARatherLongName3: 'value 2', ...),
        new MyClass(aVariableWithARatherLongName1: 'value 3', aVariableWithARatherLongName2: 2.0, aVariableWithARatherLongName3: 'value 3', ...),
        new MyClass(aVariableWithARatherLongName1: 'value 4', aVariableWithARatherLongName2: 2.0, aVariableWithARatherLongName3: 'value 4', ...),
        new MyClass(aVariableWithARatherLongName1: 'value 5', aVariableWithARatherLongName2: 2.0, aVariableWithARatherLongName3: 'value 5', ...),
    ]
}
```

Is something like this possible with Intellij (14) or are there any plugins that provide functionality like this?

Comment: Same question, searched the web, found nothing. Anyway I'll post here if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request on https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000422864-Generate-Code-from-Object-state-in-Debugger
But it doesn't seem to be implemented :(

The paying software "JTest" (that looks like being eclipse based) from Parasoft seems to do be able to generate the test based on the values of an inspected objected:
https://docs.parasoft.com/display/JTEST1040/Tracking+Object+Changes+and+Creating+Assertions

Generating the mock data shouldn't be any harder but doesn't seem to provide it either. Maybe you can add your own template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to have intellij do this by default.  So something like the groovy code below should work.  It would take a little bit more work to be able to handle a list of objects like you have in your example.

```
public class ObjectBuilder {
Object object

private static final Map PREFIXES = [(String.class): "\"", (Integer.class): "", (Boolean.class): "", (Double.class): "", (Long.class): ""]
private static final Map SUFIXES = [(String.class): "\"", (Integer.class): "", (Boolean.class): "", (Double.class): "d", (Long.class): ""]

ObjectBuilder(Object object) {
    this.object = object
}

def build() {
    List properties = []
    object.getClass().getDeclaredFields().each {
        if(!it.isSynthetic()) {
            String propertyName = it.getName()
            properties << "$propertyName: ${PREFIXES.get(it.getType())}${object[propertyName]}${SUFIXES.get(it.getType())}"
        }
    }
    println "new ${object.getClass().getSimpleName()}(${properties.join(", ")})"
}
}
```

I tested it with the following code (borrowing from your `MyClass` example:

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass()
myClass1.aVariableWithARatherLongName1 = "blah"
myClass1.aVariableWithARatherLongName2 = 2.0d
myClass1.aVariableWithARatherLongName4 = 23105
myClass1.aVariableWithARatherLongName6 = new Boolean(true)

MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass()
myClass2.aVariableWithARatherLongName1 = "other"
myClass2.aVariableWithARatherLongName2 = 4.0d
myClass2.aVariableWithARatherLongName4 = 123
myClass2.aVariableWithARatherLongName6 = new Boolean(false)


new ObjectBuilder(myClass1).build()
new ObjectBuilder(myClass2).build()
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
new MyClass(aVariableWithARatherLongName1: "blah", aVariableWithARatherLongName2: 2.0d, aVariableWithARatherLongName4: 23105, aVariableWithARatherLongName6: true)
new MyClass(aVariableWithARatherLongName1: "other", aVariableWithARatherLongName2: 4.0d, aVariableWithARatherLongName4: 123, aVariableWithARatherLongName6: false)
```